# Change Print Margins in Firefox on Mac?

Tags: macos, firefox, printing, margins

I got a call asking how to change print margins in Firefox on their new Apple computers.

The <kbd>Alt</kbd> does not reveal a menu bar (File, Edit, View, etc) so File->Page Setup is not reachable there.

Clicking the Print button in the new-style menu seems to go straight to print dialog on Mac. (on windows it goes to Print Preview and there's a Page Setup button there)

I've seen some screenshots, and it seems that I'm looking for a Page Size option, but the screenshots didn't show how to do this in the recent Firefox where they seem to have removed Page Setup.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

From the Print window, choose the Page Size dropdown and choose US Letter borderless, or Manage Custom Sizes and enter a new size. You can set the margins for this paper size at this time. Custom paper sizes will appear in the list below the printer default paper sizes.